# Could there be a correlation between the earth's magnetic field and quantum superposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

I do apologise in advance for what might seem like a stupid question coming from a non-physicist. But I was wondering if the earth’s magnetic field could influence the wave pattern that one observes in a simple double-slit experiment. Meaning, in a sense, something similar to what De Broglie-Bohm suggest where the electron/particle simply rides a 'probability wave' and then takes a position at the point of measurement. Could it be that the wave that the particle/electron is riding is actually simply the earth's magnetic field that is causing these electrons/particles to move in that way? Like a boat on a giant sea.

Again, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if there were a correlation between the double-slit pattern and the earth's magnetic field, then "north" would be a special direction with a different interference pattern.

You can do your own double-slit experiment (in the continuum limit, with photons) with a laser pointer, if you use a staple to block the "middle" of the beam. It's pretty easy to verify that the patter is exactly the same if you shine the laser on a north wall, or on a west wall, or on the ceiling. You can even stick a little permanent neodymium magnet into the photon beam. Those have surface fields around a tesla, about 20 000 times stronger that the Earth's field; you'll find that their biggest effect is that they cast a shadow.

Answer (score 1):

The Earth's magnetic field does produce a force, called the [Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), on a moving electron, but this is no different to any other magnetic field. This force is how the old style TVs moved the electron beam around to create the picture.

So there will be some effect of the Earth's magnetic field on the double slit experiment. However there is nothing mysterious about this. It will just cause the electron beams used to move sideways slightly. The interaction is unrelated to the ideas about pilot waves or indeed anything else to do with superposition. I suppose it could be a source of [decoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) - I don't know enough about that topic to estimate how big its effect would be.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will read up about decoherence to get a better idea about what you're saying.